# SQL Column merge and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, mysql, database, union, aggregate

I have a simple table with two columns (well two columns of interest, plus just an ID)... I have an ajax search which is just looking for keywords... which are then sent to my real search... the ajax search doesn't care what they are, but they need to be distinct...

How can I merge the two columns together:

```
City, Country

Krakow, Poland
Warsaw, Poland
Austin, USA
New York, USA
Prague, Czech Republic
```

So that I would get

```
Keyword, Sideinfo

Krakow, Poland
Warsaw, Poland
Austin, USA
Prague, Czech Republic
USA, Country (only once)
Poland, Country
Czech Republic, Country
```

I tried doing a UNION but I'm not sure how i'd do a WHERE LIKE 'keyword%'

Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT Keyword, SideInfo
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DISTINT City as Keyword, Country as SideInfo
    FROM Table

    UNION
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT Country, 'Country'
    FROM Table
) AS InnerQuery
Where Keyword LIKE '%blah%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select distinct country Keyword,'Country' SideInfo from Cities
union all
select City Keyword,Country SideInfo from Cities
```